# how to find a function from a folder on linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I downloaded some source codes of a program
and put it in a folder
I want to find a function declaration from the folder
on terminal, how to do it with shell command?
thanks!

Comment: What do function-declarations look like in this source-code?

Comment: I just want to look for the string from a folder, in the folder there are many files, sub-folders

Answer (score 17):

### Try doing this

using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
grep -Hri function_name .
```

if you want only the path :

```
grep -ril function_name .
```

### Explanations

- the trailing `.` stands for *current directory*
- `-i` : *case-insensitive*
- `-r` : *recursive*
- `-H` : *Print the file name for each match*
- `-l` : *Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.*

See [`man grep`](http://betterthangrep.com/)

### Last but not least

An interesting tool is [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), it will avoid searching in `.svn`, `.cvs`, `.git` dirs and such... It is designed to search code.

Example :

```
$ cd /usr/share/perl5
$ ack -r 'Larry\s+Wall'
site_perl/Inline/C.pm
370:# bindings to. This code is mostly hacked out of Larry Wall's xsubpp program.

core_perl/overload/numbers.pm
5:#    Copyright (C) 2008 by Larry Wall and others

core_perl/CPAN.pm
876:#       From: Larry Wall <larry@wall.org>
```

or just file path :

```
$ ack -rl 'Larry\s+Wall'
vendor_perl/LWP.pm
site_perl/Inline/C.pm
core_perl/overload/numbers.pm
core_perl/CPAN.pm
core_perl/SelfLoader.pm
core_perl/AutoLoader.pm
core_perl/AutoSplit.pm
core_perl/Test/Harness.pm
core_perl/XSLoader.pm
core_perl/DB.pm
```

No need the ending `.` with `ack` (compared to `grep`)

Comment: If you want to refine your search to specific file types and still use grep, you can use `--include=*.<file_postfix>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [CScope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). You also need to have vi/vim installed.

After you install it, just run the following command in the folder you want to find the function:

```
cscope -R
```

After that, a menu will appear, showing many options to find all symbols, the function definition, functions which calls the function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will go through all the files in the directory you opened and any subdirectories (though it messes up if there are spaces in a file or directory name), will search all of them for the FUNCTION that you put, and will output the path to the file and show the matching line.  Run it by `cd`ing to the directory you opened, (and replace FUNCTION with the function you're looking for).

```
find . -type f | xargs grep FUNCTION
```

Comment: why there is a `-` in between?

Comment: The `-` is necessary, but should be attached to the word `type`.  I'll fix it, thanks.